# How to do calculations with numbers separated with commas?

Tags: kotlin, calculation, decimalformat

I want to do calculations with numbers separated by thousands (**comma**), and the result will be formatted in thousands separated (**comma**) as well. *Example*:

```
var editText1 = **12,520.00**
var editText2 = **52,345.00**
var result = **64,825.00**
//
var editText1 = **12,520**
var editText2 = **52,345**
var result = **64,825.00**
```

=====================================

I just tried to format the result according to the separation in thousands (comma) of the values that I would receive.

```
//formats
decimalSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US)
format="##,###.##"
decimal = DecimalFormat(format, decimalSymbols)
decimal.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING

//Variables that will receive the values
val prov = profit.text.toString().toDouble()
val cust = costs.text.toString().toDouble()
val amort = amortizacoes.text.toString().toDouble()
val jur = interest.text.toString().toDouble()

//Formatting the result in BigDecimal
result val = (prov - cost - amort - jur) * 0.32
val parsed = BigDecimal(result)
val formatResult = decimal.format(parsed)

tax.setText(formatResult.toString())
```

Comment: As the code suggests, the characters used for separating thousands, and for separating decimal places, are locale-dependent. If you're not 100% certain that your code will never have to cope with other locales, it's probably better not to remove commas per se, but to remove whatever character the locale is using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Simply remove all commas from the string value:

  ```
  value= value.replace(",", "")
  ```
- Do your calculations
- And finally, you can use `format` to decorate and show them with commas, with:

  ```
  "%,d".format(value)
  ```

**Tested with JVM and Kotlin v1.8.0.**

Here is the playground link: https://pl.kotl.in/pXpev-dei

[image]

Code snippet, pasted here:

```
fun main() {

    var editText1 = "12,520.00";
    var editText2 = "52,345.00";
// var result = **64,825.00**
    editText1 = editText1.replace(",","");
    editText2 = editText2.replace(",","");
    
    var resDouble = editText1.toDouble() * editText2.toDouble();
    val res = "%,f".format(resDouble)
    println(res)
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `"."` is a typo in the replace method

Comment: Thank you. But I can't use "replace" because the inserted numbers are not String, because it converts to Double to be able to do the calculations in my application

Comment: @MarianoMuendane Sir, I guess you are asking for complete solution.. hope the edited answer helps... 

Please upvote and accept my answer...

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes, it was a typo indeed.... hope it gets cleared out now... i was focusing more on approach, but I think he is focusing on direct answers only...

Comment: @MarianoMuendane Are you sure you want to be using doubles, or any floating-point type? See [this question](/q/588004/10134209). If you care about exact values, then consider using e.g. BigDecimal instead.

Comment: The answer I got is working fine, but I'll have a look. thanks!